# In Ruby On Rails indexing required?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-indexes

Table->

```
create_table "subscription_plans", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "business_id"
    t.datetime "published_at"
    t.datetime "signup_end_date"
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.datetime "deactivated_at"
    t.index ["business_id", "end_time", "deactivated_at"], name: "index_plan_on_bid_published_deactivated"
    t.index ["business_id", "published_at"], name: "index_subscription_plans_on_business_id_and_published_at"
    t.index ["business_id", "signup_end_date", "end_time"], name: "index_plans_on_signup_end_date_and_end_time'"
end
```

When ever I hit query

```
SELECT `subscription_plans`.* FROM `subscription_plans` WHERE `subscription_plans`.`business_id` = 27 AND `subscription_plans`.`deactivated_at` IS NULL AND `subscription_plans`.`published_at` IS NOT NULL AND ((end_time > '2021-06-30 08:16:21.824452' OR end_time IS NULL))
```

It always uses index `index_subscription_plans_on_business_id_and_published_at`. Is there any combination where I can use `index_plan_on_bid_published_deactivated`?
Or there is not any combination of index with `deactivated_at`?

Comment: I think the problem here is that you're passing a range for the `end_time` column, rather than a specific value. As such, it wont match that index.

Comment: But I used `deactivated_at` in query also so why it's not picking up `index_plan_on_bid_published_deactivated`?

Comment: Because the index will only be used if all components can be matched.

Comment: OR clauses and performant queries don't mix

Comment: If your index was `["business_id", "deactivated_at", "end_time"]`, then _maybe_ this index would've been picked up. As it is right now (that index and that query), the `deactivated_at` of the index can't be used to narrow the search down. And so the optimizer likely finds that using this other index results in scanning fewer records.